# Writing only lower case letters to file in Python

Tags: python, file

How do I read a file in Python and write its contents to another file with the following condition:

If the character is a letter in the input file, then the letter should be made lowercase and written to the output file. Other characters should not be written.

```
def lower_case():

    file_name = input("Enter the file name to read from: ")
    tmp_read = open(str(file_name), 'r')
    tmp_read.readline()

    fileName = input("Enter the file name to write to... ")
    tmp_write = open(str(fileName), "w")
    for line in tmp_read:
        if str(line).isalpha():
            tmp_write.write(str(line).lower())
    print("Successful!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lower_case()
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you aware that you're iterating over the file by line, so if there is a single non-letter character on a line, that line will be skipped entirely? Also, all the calls to `str()` are unnecessary since the parameters already are strings.

Comment: To improve your question, provide sample input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: You are comparing an entire line, when you should be comparing each character.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Code**

```
input_f = input("Enter the file name to read from: ")
output_f = input("Enter the file name to write to... ")

fw = open(output_f, "w")

with open(input_f) as fo:
    for w in fo:
        for c in w: 
            if c.isalpha():
                fw.write(c.lower())
            if c.isspace():
                fw.write('\n')

fo.close()
fw.close()
```

*input.txt*

```
HELLO
12345
WORLD
67890
UTRECHT
030
dafsf434ffewr354tfffff44344fsfsd89087uefwerwe
```

*output.txt*

```
hello

world

utrecht

dafsfffewrtffffffsfsduefwerwe
```

**Sources**

1. [How to convert string to lowercase in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797984/how-to-convert-string-to-lowercase-in-python)
2. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readlines.htm
3. http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python
4. [How to read a single character at a time from a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988211/how-to-read-a-single-character-at-a-time-from-a-file-in-python)
5. [How to check if text is "empty" (spaces, tabs, newlines) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405292/how-to-check-if-text-is-empty-spaces-tabs-newlines-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

This checks weather a character isalpha() or isspace() then write in new file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def lower_case():

    input_name = input("Enter the file name to read from: ")
    output_name = input("Enter the file name to write to... ")

    with open(str(input_name), 'r') as i:
        content = i.readlines()
        with open(str(output_name),'wb') as o:
            for line in content:
                o.write(''.join(c for c in line if c.isalpha() or c.isspace()).lower())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lower_case()
```

Comment: why are you using `str(output_name)`?

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\case (2).py", line 13, in <module>
    lower_case()
  File "C:\case (2).py", line 10, in lower_case
    o.write(''.join(c for c in line if c.isalpha() or c.isspace()).lower())
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`

Comment: @utrecht what file are you trying to parse?

Comment: input.txt: `HELLO\n
12345\n
WORLD\n
67890`