# sed not working on large file [Looking for other options]

Tags: python, json, bash, sed, gnu

I have a gigantic json file that was accidentally output without a newline character in between all the json entries. It is being treated as one giant single line. So what I did was try and take a find an replace with sed and insert a newline.

```
sed 's/{"seq_id"/\n{"seq_id"/g' my_giant_json.json
```

It doesn't output anything

However, I know my sed expression is working if I operate on just a small part of the file and it works fine.

```
head -c 1000000 my_giant_json.json |  sed 's/{"seq_id"/\n{"seq_id"/g'
```

---

I have also tried using python with this gnarly one liner

`'\n{"seq_id'.join(open(json_file,'r').readlines()[0].split('{"seq_id')).lstrip()`

But this loads into memory thanks to readlines() method. But I don't know how to iterate through a giant single line of characters (iterate in chunks) and do a find and replace.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Read N characters at a time. Check this answer for ideas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988211/how-to-read-a-single-character-at-a-time-from-a-file-in-python

Comment: @snakecharmb - not duplicate. That would work if it was a constant number of lines between objects. But unfortunately its not.

Comment: @CrobarKZ That might work, if I right the files as chunks. Will get back.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea why sed is not working though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl will let you change the input separator (`$/`) from newline to another character. You could take advantage of this to get some convenient chunking.

```
perl -pe'BEGIN{$/="}"}s/^({"seq_id")/\n$1/' my_giant_json.json
```

That sets the input separator to be `"}"`. Then it looks for chunks that start with `{"seq_id"` and prefixes them with a newline.

Note that it puts an unnecessary empty line at the beginning. You could complicate the program to eliminate that or just delete it manually after.